# Function used in selector in iOS Swift can only be in the same file?

Tags: function, swift, ios8

I have created a time activate on the View Controller.
It needs to call a selector, and for that selector, I am calling a function.

When the function is in the View Controller file, it works. If i put this function in another Swift file that I created in the app, it does not find the Selector and I get an error during runtime.

Is it possible to put functions in Swift in different files or not?

```
@IBAction func startNotificationTimer(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "update_start", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    timerStatus.text = "Started"
}
```

"update_start" is in a different file.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what file your `update_start` method is in, but it does matter that it be a method in your View Controller class. If you define it in a file other than the one where that class is declared, you'll need to define the method in an extension on that class.

Also, `NSTimer` selectors should end with a colon (`update_start:`), because they take a single parameter (the timer) when called.